# Wordpress woocommerce 500 error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня проблема, woocommerce не отображает товар, в консоли пишет 500 ошибка. 
Как можно исправить подскажите пжл.

В каких файлах можно редактировать и переопределять функции WooCommerce? Как можно словить момент платежа?

Comment: Смотреть логи прежде всего

Comment: @SeVlad посмотрела логи выходит ошибка Call to undefined method WooCommerce::get_image_size(), тема shopDock, после обновления плагина Woocommerce появилась эта ошибка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция woocommerce `get_image_size` давно устарела и заменена `wc_get_image_size`. Последние версии woocomerce не содержат `get_image_size`, поэтому вызов этой функции из вашей темы заканчивается фатальной ошибкой.

Судя по всему, сайт очень давно не обновлялся.

Вариантов 3, собственно.

1. (Предпочтительный) Обновить тему. Разработчики уже заменили вызов устаревшей функции.
2. Откатить версию WooCommerce
3. Вручную в файлах темы заменить вызовы `get_image_size` на `wc_get_image_size` (но при этом надо понимать, что вы делаете)

Answer (score 1):

По всей вероятности у вас `PHP` ошибка, для того чтобы понять где проблема, в файле `wp-config.php` активируйте `WP_DEBUG` и поставьте `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`

Comment: можно ли редактировать wp-config в админ панели, у меня нет доступа к серверу где лежит приложение, можно ли открыть его через админ панель?

Comment: @DoctorDo через админку редактировать не получится (насколько помню), можно установить плагин и после активации, редактировать данный файл  вот ссылка https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-config-file-editor/

Comment: Ничего нельзя редактировать из админки. Без риска поломать сайт. Только через ФТП в правильных блокнотах!

Comment: @SeVlad - полностью согласен, но DoctorDo даже не сможет просмотреть логи т.к он сказал что доступа к хосту нет...

Comment: @DoctorDo - всё таки вам надо достать доступы к хостингу...

Answer (score 0):

Взяла доступы, посмотрела логи выходит ошибка, эта ошибка появилась после обновления плагина Woocommerce

```
Call to undefined method WooCommerce::get_image_size()
[Fri Feb 10 09:25:57 2017] [error] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method WooCommerce::get_image_size()
```

Comment: И дальше написано где именно. Наверняка ж на тему показывает. Тема куплена или "бесплатно" с  помойки скачана?. Если тема легальная - обновить. А нет -  купить или сменить на безопасную

Comment: тема бесплатная и легальная

Comment: Темы нет в оф каталоге https://wordpress.org/themes/search/ShopDock/. потому что она платная https://themify.me/themes/shopdock.

Comment: @SeVlad в каких файлах можно переопределить функции WooCommerce?

Comment: Да причем тут переопределить? Тут в теме проблема. И не одна. В ней шеллы/вирусы, это во первых. А во вторых - нерабочие функции.

Comment: @SeVlad, да проблема решилась, сейчас вопрос как дописать функции, т. е. на момент когда происходит платеж добавить функции, н-р вывод, работу с бд.

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. А этот стоит отметить решенным.